# Negative cycle of even length

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, weighted-graphs

Given an undirected graph $(V,E)$ with weights on edges $\in Z$ is it possible to find a negative cycle of **even** length (not the weight of the cycle, but the number of edges contained in the cycle) in polynomial time?

Formally:

Find a sequence of vertices $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k,v_1\}$ such that

1. For every $i$, edge $(v_i,v_{i+1})$ exists
2. $\sum w_{v_i,v_{i+1}}$ is negative
3. $|\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k,v_1\}|$ is odd (i.e. number of edges is even)
4. $v_i \neq v_j$ except for $v_1$ which is duplicated twice (at the start and at the end of the sequence)

### Motivation:

A simpler implementation of minimum weighted maximal matching in non bipartite graphs. I would like to investigate a possibility of a simpler and more intuitive implementation of minimum weighted maximal matching which does not use unintuitive and unexplainable duality theory. One such flavor is is possible for bipartite graphs:

1. Find any maximum matching
2. Assign weights $c_{ij}$ for edges not in macthing and $-c_{ij}$ for edges in matching
3. Find a negative cycle. In bipartite graph, if it exists, it always has an even length. Flip edges along this cycle to improve overall cost of matching.

Such algorithm is not possible for general graphs because of the assumption that all cycles have even length

### What approaches I have tried

I tried checking if it is possible to modify Bellman-Ford in some way to search even length cycles. Alas, it seems impossible. In classic negative cycle search algorithm you perform Bellman-Ford iteration N times and then try to unwind "parent" array. If negative cycle existed it will be present when following "parent" pointers, but unwinded cycle has arbitrary length.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I know that if you ask for the _shortest_ (fewest edges) such, it becomes NP-hard. See arXiv:2308.12653

Comment: @PålGD, yep, turns out NP hard. I will close the answer.

Comment: Without the requirement to avoid repeating vertices, this can be solved in polynomial time using Bellman-Ford on the graph $(V',E')$ with $V'=V \times \{0,1\}$ and $E'=\{(u,b) \to (v,1-b) \mid u \to v \in E, b \in \{0,1\}\}$.

Comment: @D.W. your solution may also use arc multiple times. Consider $G = (\{\,1, 2, 3\,\}, \{\,(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1)\,\})$.